# Modify Python stack

Tags: python, python-3.x

### Background

I have some library code that uses `traceback.walk_stack` (iterator version of `extract_stack`) to find what file the user is calling it from. This is useful for many things, such as printing file & line of the calling function during logging. My use case is more involved than logging, but the principle is the same.

## Problem

Normally the user calls this function from Python code, but now they can specify a config file, and I call it during parsing. I want this library call to find the location of the config file rather than the location of my parsing code.

## Question

Can I modify the stack that `traceback.walk_stack` returns and add my own synthetic entry?

- Yes, I'm aware of the XY problem, thus the long preamble. Yes I know this is gross and terrible, and I am ashamed of myself, but it is honestly the cleanest answer I can think of right now.

Comment: I figured out a workaround: before calling this library method, I am setting a global static variable with the location of the config file, then clearing it afterwards. It's probably less ugly than messing with the stack. Nonetheless, I'm curious if there are any solutions to the actual question I posed.